# Replacing Placeholders with Integers from list and format an Excel Row using openPyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a list:

[10, 18, 529, 657]

I want to loop through the above list and replace XX in the first line below with 10 then 18 then 529 and 657 :

```
for rows in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=XX, max_row=XX, min_col=1):
    for cell in rows:
      cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color='c9e1f8',end_color='c9e1f8',fill_type='solid')
```

so it would look below for example:

```
for rows in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=10, max_row=10, min_col=1):
    for cell in rows:
      cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color='c9e1f8',end_color='c9e1f8',fill_type='solid')
```

I am trying to grasp how to approach this. Any suggestions?

Then I can apply the row coloring based on the supplied list. Been battling this for days and keep hitting dead ends. Any advice or ideas on other approaches appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you need to use another loop enclosing this one. Say `lst = [10, 18, 529, 657]`- then

```
for XX in lst:
    for rows in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=XX, max_row=XX, min_col=1):
        for cell in rows:
            cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color='c9e1f8',end_color='c9e1f8',fill_type='solid')
```

If this doesn't meet your requirement, please give further explanation of your task.